# Account Confirmation and Password Reset with web api and ASP.NET Identity using phone number instead of email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity

I'm Trying to Develop Api Where Users Can Register With Their Phone Number As UserName

Currently, I'm Facing Account Confirmation and Password Reset using Phone Number so I'm Wondering is There Support for This (Account Locking Until User Verifies It's Account By SMS token, token generation, and token invalidation ) in  Identity or I should Go My Own Way

Thank in Advance And Any Thing can  Help

Comment: Try Twilio: https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/account-verification-csharp-mvc#building-blocks